Is the product of two Montel Sequences also a Montel Sequence?
Definition (Montel Sequence)
$f_k \in A(\mathbb{D}^n)$ is a Montel Sequence, if $f_k |_{\mathbb{D}^n} \overset{weak^*}{\longrightarrow} 0$ in $H^{\infty} (\mathbb{D}^n)$.
If I have two of such Montel Sequences $f_k$ and $g_k$, will their product $f_k \cdot g_k$ also be a Montel Sequence?
I can't find anything on the internet about it, let alone at least something about Montel Sequences. I thought about using the scalar product somehow and approximating it from above to zero, but I don't know whether this would be the right approach.

Can you define your notation especially the set and the weak convergence you're talking about.

@EDX What set? $A(\mathbb{D}^n)$ is the polydisc algebra, $H^{\infty} (\mathbb{D}^n)$ is the Hardy space on the polydisc. The weak* convergence is just the analogue of the weak convergence but for the dual space (= for functions on $\mathbb{D}^n$ in this case). This is why I got the idea with the scalar product (writing out something like $\langle (f_k \cdot g_k)(x), y \rangle$ maybe for $x,y \in \mathbb{D}^n$). I honestly don't know what else I should explain, as they are pretty standard definitions in analysis?

Ok thanks that good enough :)

@EDX Do you maybe know how I could solve my problem?

I'm looking at it now : once you've expressed the dual of $H^{\infty}$, you express weak convergence in terms of integral scalar product, yet Cauchy-Schwarz isn't working directly, Have you the expression o the dual o $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D}^n)$ and its inner stability operations (is it stable by product, by squaring etc...) ?
